# How to retrieve images shown in edit form using jQuery.filer file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, image, file

I am using the [jQuery.filer plugin](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer) drag and drop method. It's working fine when uploading.

How do I retrieve those images and show them in an edit form?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed up the grammar in your question people will better understand it. I would also suggest describing what you've tried so far. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: [https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer/](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer#options--features), you need to use **files** option.

```
$('input').filer({
     files: [
         {
            name: "appended_file.jpg",
            size: 5453,
            type: "image/jpg",
            file: "/path/to/file/appended_file.jpg"
         }
     ]
});
```

Comment: how do we add multipal files by usinf loop

Comment: according do documentation: http://filer.grandesign.md/#documentation, you should use API method: **append**

`
var filerKit = $("#file_input").prop("jFiler");
filerKit.append( file_object )
`